# Color Palette reverses for different years in KMeans (GEE)

Tags: google-earth-engine, clustering, google-colab

I am trying to cluster the image using GEE API into 2 classes and the algorithm is working fine but when I am visualizing, the colors reverse. That is, for year1 -> class1: green, class2: yellow but for year2 the colors revert for the same lines of code. Year2 -> class1: yellow, class2: green.

**Code**:

```
def kmeans(year):
  training = year.sample(**{
    'region': country,
    'scale': 30,
    'numPixels': 5000
  })

  #Instantiate the clusterer and train it.
  clusterer = ee.Clusterer.wekaKMeans(2).train(training)

  #Cluster the input using the trained clusterer.
  result = year.cluster(clusterer)
  return result

###VISUALIZATION

def vis_kmeans(previous_year, next_year):
  Map = geemap.Map()
  #Display the clusters with random colors.
  kmeansVis = {'min':-1, 'max':1, 'palette':['green', 'yellow']}
  Map.addLayer(previous_year, kmeansVis,  'year1')
  Map.addLayer(next_year, kmeansVis,  'year2')
  Map.centerObject(country, 10) #to adjust the zoom center
  return Map
```

**Output Year1:**
[image: Year1]

**Output Year2:**
[image: Year2]

Why are the colors reverting? How do I avoid it?

Comment: It is because the cluster value *k* is meaningless and independent for each run of the algorithm. The values are clustered but *not* categorised.

Comment: @Matt So, how do we mitigate this problem? As KMeans is unsupervised then how do we tell the algorithm that assign a certain color to that pixel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the image histograms vary from image to image, the per-image clusterer may group pixels differently. If you want the same pixel characteristics to be in the same group you should create a single trained `ee.Clusterer` from an image that represents the spectra well and apply it to all image. The following is a modified example from your post.

```py
import ee
from IPython.display import Image

ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()

def kmeans_clusterer(img, region):
  """Returns a trained ee.Clusterer."""
  training = img.sample(**{
    'region': region,
    'scale': 30,
    'numPixels': 5000
  })
  return ee.Clusterer.wekaKMeans(2).train(training)

def kmeans_cluster(img, trainedCluster):
  """Returns a cluster image from input ee.Image and trained ee.Cluster."""
  return img.cluster(clusterer)

def kmeans_vis(classed_img, region, max_dim):
  """Returns an RGB visualization URL of a 2-class clustered ee.Image."""
  kmeans_vis = {'min': 0, 'max': 1, 'palette': ['green', 'yellow']}
  vis_img = classed_img.visualize(**kmeans_vis)
  return vis_img.getThumbURL({'region': region, 'dimensions': max_dim})

def get_thumb_url(img, clusterer):
    """Wrapper for applying clusterer and creating RGB visualization."""
    clusters = kmeans_cluster(img, clusterer)
    clusters_vis = kmeans_vis(clusters, region, 512)
    return clusters_vis
    
# Demo with two images.
img1 = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_TOA/LC09_046027_20220805').select('B[1-7]')
img2 = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_TOA/LC09_046027_20220720').select('B[1-7]')
region = ee.Geometry.BBox(-122.84, 47.02, -120.78, 47.83)

# Cluster training is based on img2.
clusterer = kmeans_clusterer(img2, region)

# Apply the trained clusterer to both images and visualize the result.
display(Image(url=get_thumb_url(img1, clusterer)))
display(Image(url=get_thumb_url(img2, clusterer)))
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you used `.visualized` and `getThumbURL`? I am unable to use this code for the said purpose.

Comment: I have successfully executed your code but when I change the K (number of clusters) for instance to 3 or 4 then it again changes the color of the clusters. Is this code not consistent?

Comment: When you change the number of classes, the class definitions change because the image histogram(s) are now divided into 4 sections, instead of 3 sections, the break lines in the data cloud are different for 3 class and 4 classes. Also your code gradient of green to yellow is now stretched across 4 classes instead of 3, so the colors will appear different as well.

Comment: So, for more classes the code needs to be changed, right?

Comment: You'd need to change the `max` argument for visualization to the number of `wekaKMeans` minus 1.

Comment: I did that and changed the palette colors too. But didn't work.