# Assigning colors to the clusters in KMeans. (GEE - PythonAPI)

Tags: google-earth-engine, clustering, google-maps-api

How do we assign a color to one class of KMeans and another color to another class? So, when the algorithm is run for another year then it should assign the same color to the same class.

Code:

```
def kmeans(year):
  training = year.sample(**{
    'region': country,
    'scale': 30,
    'numPixels': 5000
  })

  #Instantiate the clusterer and train it.
  clusterer = ee.Clusterer.wekaKMeans(2).train(training)

  #Cluster the input using the trained clusterer.
  result = year.cluster(clusterer)
  return result

###VISUALIZATION

def vis_kmeans(previous_year, next_year):
  Map = geemap.Map()
  #Display the clusters with random colors.
  kmeansVis = {'min':-1, 'max':1, 'palette':['green', 'yellow']}
  Map.addLayer(previous_year, kmeansVis,  'year1')
  Map.addLayer(next_year, kmeansVis,  'year2')
  Map.centerObject(country, 10) #to adjust the zoom center
  return Map
```

If I run the above code then what it does is: year1 -> class1:green, class2: yellow; year2 -> class1: yellow, class2:green.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Color Palette reverses for different years in KMeans (GEE)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/446026/color-palette-reverses-for-different-years-in-kmeans-gee)

Comment: @DanielWiell There is no answer on the shared post.