# Saving layer as .tiff file using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, layer-file

I have an NDVI map for which I changed the symbology in ArcMap. Now, I want to export this as a .tiff file and then import this .tiff file in Google Earth Engine.

Can we save a layer as .tiff file in ArcMap?

I tried to export it but it removes all the processing (symbology etc) that I performed. Whereas, when I save it as a layer then Google Earth Engine gives me an error:

> The file named "image.tif.lyr" does not have a correct extension.

Comment: @user2856 I have edited the question. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: No. You can't use ArcGIS symbology in GEE, just recreate the symbology in GEE https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_visualization

Comment: @user2856 I have tried to do that. I tried to cluster the image and then visualized it but the problem is that when I try to cluster the image for a different year then different labels are assigned. I have asked the question here to but still got no answer that's why I tried to do that in ArcMap: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/446026/color-palette-reverses-for-different-years-in-kmeans-gee

Comment: Export a layout to geotif or export your view to one.

Comment: The .lyr file is the symbology (i.e., the number of classes and the colors you created during the symbolization of your raster in `ArcMap`). As @user2856 said, you need to recreate the symbology in `GEE`. For the definition of the lyr file have a look here (https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011516)